# How can I get the next weekday in Perl?

Tags: perl, time

I am trying to calculate the next day (e.g. Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday etc) using the variables below.

Example: localtime day is Wednesday and I require Thursday, the offset being +1, day is Thursday and I require Monday, offset being +4

```
my @days = qw(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday);
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime
```

Is there some sort of algorithm I can work out to do this? I am unable to use DateTime & Time::Piece library in Perl as a restriction.

I was using:

```
my $daysToAdd = 8 - $wday; # picks up how many days there is until next Monday
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the next weekday (M-F, opposite of weekend) or the next day of the week? If the former, the next weekday after Thursday is Friday, not Monday.

Comment: I wish to find the next Monday, if it is currently Monday, I wish for it to find next week. If that helps.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it. Please [edit] your question to say that, it's currently very unclear (Schwern thought you were asking how to add one day).

Comment: Sorry about that, I have fixed up the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic date handling in Perl, throw away `localtime` and use the built in [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) class. [It will do basic date math](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece#Date-Calculations).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;  # Some useful constants like ONE_DAY

my $now = Time::Piece->new;
say $now;

my $tomorrow = $now + ONE_DAY;
say $tomorrow;
```

---

As far as calculating the offset between two week days, map them to numbers and use those numbers.  Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.  The algorithm for figuring out how many days you have to advance between two weekdays is...

```
(7 - $current_dow + $new_dow) % 7
```

To expand that out: `7 - $current_dow` is how many days from the current day to the end of the week. Then you add your desired day onto that. The whole thing is mod 7 (so 8 becomes 1) to handle the case of moving just a few days forward (ie. Wednesday to Friday).

Doing it for Friday to Thursday is...

```
(7 - 5 + 4) % 7
(2 + 4) % 7
6 % 7
6
```

Doing it for Friday to Saturday is...

```
(7 - 5 + 6) % 7
(2 + 6) % 7
8 % 7
1
```

And here's the code.

```
my $day = 4; # Thursday
my $days_offset = (7 - $now->day_of_week + $day) % 7;
my $thursday = $now + ($days_offset * ONE_DAY);
say $thursday;
```

Comment: I am unable to use Time::Piece as another restriction

Comment: @JohnnyDoey Why can't you use Time::Piece? The usual reason people say they can't use modules is because they can't install them, but Time::Piece been a core module since Perl 5.10; odds are good that you already have it.

Comment: Yeah I've tried. The servers we're given can't be updated by me and their Perl 5.16 doesn't seem to have Time::Piece.

Comment: $ perl file1.pl
Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at file1.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at file1.pl line 8.

Comment: @JohnnyDoey Are you on a Red Hat variant like Fedora/CentOS/Scientific Linux/Oracle Linux, by any chance? If so, ask your sysadmin to install the `perl-core` package so you can actually have a fully functional perl installation. If you're on some other platform, ask your sys admin to fix it in the manner suitable for that platform.

Comment: @JohnnyDoey Some distributions separate perl from its modules, so it may be a matter of simply installing another package like [`perl-modules`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/perl-modules). It being a package install should make installing it more palatable, and explain it will save you a lot of coding time (and bugs). Either way, you can limp along with `localtime`, the algorithm is the same, but date math will be harder.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes it seems to be running on Red Hat Enterprise 7.2. Seeing as these servers are my universities it might be a little bit more difficult getting someone to install perp-core, haha. Thanks for that I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Schwern That was the algorithm I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: No, you can't correctly do it using `localtime`; you have to use `gmtime`. (`gmtime(timegm(localtime()) + $seconds)`). Even then, it can give results that don't exist in your time zone.

Comment: @ikegami Correct, I will be using gmtime to output the time. I was using localtime to get the current time.